# VS Code and Node.js debugging

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am building an application in node.js with VS Code...

the application have multiple .js files:

- buyBOT.js
- getDeposit.js
- getTransaction.js

when I run the debug I would expect to run within the selected .js file, but instead it always stars to run in the first .js file (buyBOT.js)...

For example:

Scenario 1) I am in the buyBOT.js I "press F5" to start debug and everything is fine... (buyBOT.js debugging)

Scenario 2) I am in the getDeposit.js I "press F5" to start debug and instead of running the code in getDeposit.js, the debugger bring up buyBOT.js and start the debug there.

What am I doing wrong? is there a parameter to change/set?

Comment: Check out this link https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations Whatever a "simple app" is you may have exceeded it and thus need a launch.json file with "program": "${file}" so that it uses the current file.

Comment: Thanks! I have actually checked my folder and VisualStudio created a new folder 

`.vscode`

including a 

`launch.json`

file where is specify the "start Point"... I might have click something around.... but thanks for pointing out that article... it helped me on finding the problem!